# How to create same popupbox like in facebook.?

Tags: facebook, popupwindow

How to create same popupbox like in facebook.The problem is that in which langugae should make popupbox as same like facebook have.It require ajax or somewhat like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery / ajax for making those , they are called modal windows , just search in the net for jquery plugins for making Modal windows . You will get them .

Answer (score 0):

Some popups from Facebook can be spawned using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/ or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

```
Add Page Tab Dialog
Feed Dialog
Friends Dialog
OAuth Dialog
Pay Dialog
Requests Dialog
Send Dialog
```

For different languages, check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/